# what does the line int *(*(x[3])())[5]; do in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, function-pointers

This is my first time asking a question on Stack Overflow, so please fell free to tell me if I did anything wrong or not specific enough.
I've been programming microcontrollers in C for about 4 now. Some days ago I took part in an Electronics Competition. One of the many questions was what exactly the C codeline

```
int *(*(x[3])())[5];
```

does. This is the line as I remember it. It is possible that a bracket was at an other location, but I think this was the line.

My guess is that x is an array of functionpointers of which we take the fourth element and dereference it. This function is then executed without handing over parameters. The returnvalue seems to be a pointer to a pointer an array of which we dereference once in order to get the address of the first element. We then choose the 6th element of that array. I have no idea what the int is for though...

Thank you very much for answering my question and have a nice day.

Comment: It "declares x as array 3 of function returning pointer to array 5 of pointer to int", as pointed out [here](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int+*%28*%28x%5B3%5D%29%28%29%29%5B5%5D%3B).

Comment: Use http://cdecl.org/ to answer such questions for yourself, it's quicker than asking on StackOverflow, and avoids having ten thousand similar questions asking about one very specific declaration.

Comment: Well that was a fast answer. Thank you for showing me this site and the answer to my question!!

Comment: The real answer to your question, or the thing you should be questioning, is the value in this since it's a garbage declaration, it won't compile cause it's an error, and, by itself, it doesn't "do" anything being only a declaration.

Comment: *what does the line int *(*(x[3])())[5]; do in C?*  Provide proof of the necessity of `typedef`.

Comment: Obfuscate things unnecessarily and make stupid programmers think they're smart?

Comment: @alk In both clang and gcc: error: 'x' declared as array of functions of type 'int *(*())[5]'

Comment: @Rob: You are correct, sry. Cleaning up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to read hairy declarations like this is to find the leftmost identifier and work your way out, remembering the following precedence rules:

```
*a[n]      -- a is an array of pointer
(*a)[n]    -- a is a pointer to an array
*f()       -- f is a function returning a pointer
(*f)()     -- f is a pointer to a function
```

Applying these rules, we get

```
        x             -- x is a
        x[3]          -- 3-element array of
       (x[3])()       -- function returning
      *(x[3])()       -- pointer to
     (*(x[3])())[5]   -- 5 element array of
    *(*(x[3])())[5]   -- pointer to
int *(*(x[3])())[5];  -- int
```

As written, this declaration isn't valid; you can't have an array of function type.  I imagine it was supposed to be something like

```
int *(*(*x[3])())[5];
```

where `x` is an array of *pointers* to functions returning pointers to arrays of pointers to int.

Answer (score 5):

Use `cdecl`:

```
$ cdecl
cdecl> explain int *(*(x[3])())[5]
declare x as array 3 of function returning pointer to array 5 of pointer to int
```

It's what `cdecl` wrote above.

Comment: Woa... never saw cdecl before. Very cool

Answer (score 0):

When you cannot access a tool to translate a declaration for you, you can remember this threes rules of thumbs

1. There are three basic atoms (excluding type names)

   Atom `[n]` translates to *Array (with n elements) of*.
   Atom `()` translates to *Function(s) returning*.
   Atom `*` translates to *Pointer(s) to*.
2. Start from the *identifier* moving **right**, whenever you encounter an atom, translate it.
3. A closed facing parenthesis<sup>1</sup> or the end of line reverse the direction of parsing.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>This means `)` when moving *right*, `(` when moving left.</sub>

---

A super pedantic translation of `int *(*(x[3])())[5]` is below.

- Start from the identifier, `x`.
  Translation: **x is**
  Parsing: `int *(*(-[3])())[5]`
  Direction: Right.
- Found atom, `[3]`.
  Translation: *x is* **an array (with 3 elements) of**
  Parsing: `int *(*(---)())[5]`
  Direction: Right.
- Found `)`, reverse direction.
  Translation: *x is an array (with 3 elements) of*
  Parsing: `int *(*(----())[5]`
  Direction: **Left**.
- Found `(`, reverse direction.
  Translation: *x is an array (with 3 elements) of*
  Parsing: `int *(*-----())[5]`
  Direction: **Right**.
- Found atom `()`.
  Translation: *x is an array (with 3 elements) of* **functions returning**
  Parsing: `int *(*-------)[5]`
  Direction: Right.
- Found `)`, reverse direction.
  Translation: *x is an array (with 3 elements) of functions returning*
  Parsing: `int *(*--------[5]`
  Direction: **Left**.
- Found atom `*` 
  Translation: *x is an array (with 3 elements) of functions returning* **a pointer to**
  Parsing: `int *(---------[5]`
  Direction: Left.
- Found `(`, reverse direction 
  Translation: *x is an array (with 3 elements) of functions returning a pointer to*
  Parsing: `int *----------[5]`
  Direction: **Right**.
- Found atom `[5]`
  Translation: *x is an array (with 3 elements) of functions returning a pointer* **to an array (with 5 elements) of **
  Parsing: `int *------------`
  Direction: Right.
- End of line, reverse direction.
  Translation: *x is an array (with 3 elements) of functions returning a pointer to an array (with 5 elements) of *
  Parsing: `int *------------`
  Direction: **Left**.
- Found atom `*`.
  Translation: *x is an array (with 3 elements) of functions returning a pointer to an array (with 5 elements) of * **pointers to**
  Parsing: `int -------------`
  Direction: Left.
- Found type name `int`.
  Translation: *x is an array (with 3 elements) of functions returning a pointer to an array (with 5 elements) of pointers to* **ints**
  Parsing: `-----------------`
  Direction: Left.

Translation: *x is an array (with 3 elements) of functions returning a pointer to an array (with 5 elements) of pointers to* *ints*.

---

You can also experiment on removing parenthesis:

`int **(x[3]())[5]` translate to *x is an array (with 3 elements) of functions returning an array (with 5 elements) of pointers to pointers to ints*.

`int **x[3]()[5]` translate to *x is an array (with 3 elements) of functions returning an array (with 5 elements) of pointers to pointers to ints*.
Same as above!

Of course this is quite error prone, I kept [cdecl](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/) handy in writing this answer!