# Function returning pointer to array 5 of pointer to int

Tags: c, arrays, function

I read this question: [what does the line int *(*(x[3])())[5]; do in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37364198/what-does-the-line-int-x35-do-in-c#37364198)

which have the code line:

```
int *(*(*x[3])())[5];
```

in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37364752/4386427

According to [http://cdecl.org/](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+*%28*%28*x%5B3%5D%29%28%29%29%5B5%5D%3B) this means

> declare x as array 3 of pointer to function returning pointer to array 5 of pointer to int

Now I'm wondering about this part:

> function returning pointer to array 5 of pointer to int

How does the proto-type for a function returning pointer to array 5 of pointer to int look?

I tried this:

```
int* g()[5]    <---- ERROR: 'g' declared as function returning an array
{
    int** t = NULL;
    // t = malloc-stuff
    return t;
}
```

which doesn't compile.

Then I tried

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *(*(*x[3])())[5];

int** g()
{
    int** t = NULL;
    // t = malloc-stuff
    return t;
}

int main(void) {
    x[0] = g;
    return 0;
}
```

which compiles fine but now the return type is more like `pointer to pointer to int`. There is nothing that says `pointer to array 5 of pointer to int`

So my question is:

Is it at all possible to write a function which returns `pointer to array 5 of pointer to int` ?

If yes, how does the proto-type look?

If no, what is the purpose of `5` in the declaration of `x`?

```
int *(*(*x[3])())[5];
                  ^
                what does 5 mean here?
```

Comment: troll? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313324/are-stupid-questions-being-asked-to-trick-and-fool-so-members

Comment: @NiallCosgrove - what do you mean? Please elaborate.

Comment: @NiallCosgrove - It is indeed a genuine question.

Comment: `int* (*g())[5]` More parentheses are clearly the universal antidote, as more indirection is a panacea.

Comment: @EOF - Great - it compiles fine with your  suggestion. Still, I'm puzzled as I can assign `x[1]=g2;` even when `int* (*g())[2]` (i.e. 3 instead of 5). I don't get any warnings - at least not here: http://ideone.com/mVt8g9

Answer (score 1):

an `array[5]` of **ints** would be:

```
int array[5]; /* read: array of 5 ints */
```

and a pointer to that array (not just to the first element of it, but the whole array of 5!) would be:

```
int(* ptr)[5] = &array; /* read: pointer to an array of 5 ints */
```

and a function returning such a pointer would be:

```
int(* g())[5]; /*read: a function returning a pointer to an array of 5 ints */
```

**Following the same logic**, an `array[5]` of **pointers_to_int** would be:

```
int* array_of_ptrs[5]; /* read: array of 5 pointers_to_int */
```

and a pointer to that array would be:

```
int* (* PTR)[5] = &array_of_ptrs; /* read: pointer to an array of 5 pointers_to_int */
```

and theeeen a function returning such a pointer would be:

```
int* (* g())[5] /* read: function returning a pointer to an array of 5 pointers_to_int*/
/* just like @EOF said in the comments above! */
```

Let's try it out:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int array[5] ={1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

int a = 6, b = 7, c = 8, d = 9, e = 10;
int* array_of_ptrs[5] = {&a, &b, &c, &d, &e};

int(* g())[5] 
{
    return &array;
}

int* (* gg())[5]
{
    return &array_of_ptrs; 
}

int main()
{
int(* ptr)[5]; 
ptr = g();

int* (* PTR)[5];     
PTR = gg();
    
printf
("the value of the dereferenced 1st element of array_of_ptrs is: %d", *(*PTR)[0]);  

return 0;
}
```

clang prog.c -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu89 output:

> the value of the dereferenced 1st element of array_of_ptrs is: 6